# Добавление в реестр COM-порта для Bluetooth устройства

Tags: winapi, com-порт, c, c++, bluetooth

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые пользователи.

Помогите разобраться с ключом bluetooth-устройства в реестре. Если вы когда-либо ранее добавляли bluetooth-девайс в ОС Windows, то вам знакома следующая процедура:

- включаем bluetooth на устройстве, делаем его видимым;
- осуществляем поиск bleutooth-устройств средствами ОС;
- в списке устройств, доступных для добавления, появляется идентификатор (имя) вашего устройства;
- выбирая данное устройство из списка вам предлагается ввести секретный ключ;
- вводим и пусть секретный ключ введён успешно;
- в реестр системы добавляется COM-порт со свободным порядковым номером (а может, как-то иначе этот номер выбирается);
- в реестр добавляется виртуальный COM-порт для данного устройства, который непонятно для чего нужен. Соединение с ним производится, но отправить в него ничего не удаётся.

Собственно, необходимо вышеуказанную процедуру воспроизвести средствами C/C++. Да и возможно ли это? Затем, после работы, необходимо КОРРЕКТНО удалить устройство из реестра, чтобы при следующем добавлении не возникло проблем/ошибок.

Решение данного вопроса необходимо для работы с устройством, при помощи функций WinAPI (соединение с портом, разъединение и транспортировка данных туда и обратно).

Помогите кто чем сможет. Приму в дар полезные советы, ссылки, работающий код, пожелания удачи в решении вопроса. :) Спасибо!